# What is the difference between two Component registration in Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

```
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(new PostRepository()).As<IPostRepository>();

containerBuilder.RegisterType<PostRepository>().As<IPostRepository>();
```

I have been going through the web trying to integrate [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) into my Web Api Application. I keep running into above component registrations.

Are those two types of registration the same, if not is one better than the other and in what way???

**Posts i have read**

[Autofac](http://autofac.org/)

[Integrating with ASP.NET Web API](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration)

[Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API using Autofac](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2012/04/01/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-web-api-using-autofac.aspx)

[Autofac and ASP.NET Web API System.Web.Http.Services.IDependencyResolver Integration](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/autofac-and-asp-net-web-api-system-web-http-services-idependencyresolver-integration)

Comment: With `RegisterInstance` you will create **one** `PostRepository` so everywhere you request `IPostRepository` you get the **same** instance. With this `RegisterType<PostRepository>().As<IPostRepository>();` you will get a **different** `PostRepository` instance every tyime you request a `IPostRepository`. So none of them is better they are doing completely different things and to decide which one to use is only depends on your requirements...

Comment: @nemesv that's the answer. You should post it as such.